# textarea innerHtml output in asp.net mvc?

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, textarea

This is my textarea :

```
<div>@Html.TextAreaFor(m => m.Article.ArticleContent, new { @class = "my_textarea", id = "textareaInput" })
```

and script :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#textareaInput').click(function () {
            var htmlStr = $('#textareaInput').val();
            $('#textareaInput').val($('<div/>').text(htmlStr).html());
        });
    });
</script>
```

when I write `<p>some code</p>` output is : `&lt;p&gt;some code&lt;/p&gt;`  . But I expect : `some code`.

How may I do this? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your intention is to clear the tags, then try `$('<div/>').html(htmlStr).text()`:

```
    $(document).ready(function () {

        $('#textareaInput').change(function () {

            var htmlStr = $('#textareaInput').val();
            $('#textareaInput').val( $.trim( $('<div/>').html(htmlStr).text() ) );

        });
    });
```